# Stopping a .py file from running in background using kill -9 doesn't work

Tags: bash, python, kill

I have a .py file running in the background, invoked with:

```
python file.py &
```

Now I try to stop it as using:

```
$ ps -fA | grep python
root     31032     1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 python home/file.py
$ kill -9 1
```

This does not work. I thought `kill -9` was a sure fire way to shut down a process using its pid, but it seems weird that the pid for the .py file is 1 in the first place.

How do i stop this file?

Comment: The process number is 31032.

Comment: You should have run `kill 31032`

Comment: Terrance, and M., next time feel free to answer the question as an answer and not just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PID is 31032, the next number (1) is the PPID (Parent Process ID).

You want to kill the PID of 31032.

If you want to see the headers which show what each column means, run `ps` without the `grep` command, and the first line printed will be a description of the column.